# Height or antenna gain for a ship mast cell antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, cellphone, distance

I'm optimizing my ship's WAN using cellular modems and looking to improve distance connectivity over speed in an either or option challenge.

Our ship's mast has two cell antennas which are currently 15 meters above water.  Given the earth curvature, is height going to make more difference than a higher gain dBi antenna?  It would take a decent amount of work, but I could get them to about 21 meters. (All using LMR400 cable.)

Cell phone towers are obviously variable in height, but figuring an average of 100 meters (from [Steelintheair.com](https://www.steelintheair.com/blog/cell-tower-heights-across-the-us/)), then theoretically the antenna to antenna line of sight is 30.88 nautical miles (from [translatorscafe.com](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/calculator/radio-line-of-sight/)).  Raising it to 21 meters gives me 32.46 nautical miles.

We have an older 1dBi gain omni whip antenna in the 600-850 MHz ranges which is usable, but could be replaced.  I am figuring the lower frequency range will be the best distance (USA LTE Band 5, 12, 14, 17, 71 and WCDMA Band 5.)

Currently the best we've achieved is about 17 nautical miles, however there was weather during this period (so both fog/clouds, precipitation, and significant waves.)

Comment: just to be sure: this is about shore-to-ship comms, with the cellular network on shore, and not about satellite cellular or vessel2vessel communications?

Comment: by the way, 17 nautical miles: that's pretty respectable! I'm sure, due to the speed of light and finite scheduling times, there's an upper limit for the eNodeB-user equipment distance, anyway, so not quite sure how far you can even get with arbitrarily good transmission systems!

Comment: The water surface helps but also can cause diffusion and Ricean nulls.  Gain is tradeoff with direction in both vertical and horizontal directions. Then it depends how that signal is distributed inside the ship for losses and reflections to end-user or modem to WiFi and they also have the same Ricean losses.   So distributed repeaters for WiFi that share bandwidth use a special protocol in the setup. But it has to be birectional for gain which are usually 30 MHz?  apart. If I recall on cellular. so high gain Rx with a notch on Tx and visa versa is what I would look for.

Comment: The height gain is by the square root (h) but if it the antenna had a gimbal to compensate for ship angle, then if angle is as much as the antenna 1/gain or vertical beam width you lose half power, that could be reduced,  but I haven't seen these. If isotopic is 360 deg and gain is 10 then half angle beam width is 36/2 deg https://www.ahsystems.com/EMC-formulas-equations/Antenna-Factor-Gain-calculation.php

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes it's ship-to-shore to terrestrial cellular network using commercial networks (T-Mobile, AT&T, possibly others in the future).

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the antennas are on our antenna mast and have a relatively clean view of the horizon, say 20 degree obscured.  Internally we use Cisco for switches and APs, on both 2.4 & 5Ghz.  The gimbal antenna idea is interesting, much like our VSAT dish antennas. I'm similarly curious if they exist for cellular frequencies, although I wonder if several sector antennas might be cheaper and reduce moving parts.

Comment: Diversity antennae need to be autonomous sensing RSSI or packet loss to switch dynamically unless precisely phase array aligned due to lobe cancellation , I think